# Mid point pentagon, maximization of perimeter under constraint

Tags: geometry, inequality, plane-geometry, polygons, experimental-mathematics

Let $ABCDE$ be a convex pentagon of perimeter $\mathcal{P}$.
Consider $F,G,H,I,J$ the mid points of $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$, etc.
Denote $\mathcal{Q}$ the perimeter of the pentagon $FGHIJ$.

If $ABCDE$ is regular, with high school geometry tools we can easily show that $\frac{\mathcal{Q}}{\mathcal{P}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4} = \sin (3\pi/10)$.

I am interested to show that for every convex pentagon (not just regular) we have $\frac{\mathcal{Q}}{\mathcal{P}} \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$. I do not have a proof (yet) but computer simulations seem to indicate that the result is true.

Like many problems of the sort, regularity offers a maximum (for instance isoperimetric inequalities https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality).

If we cannot get $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{4}$, I would still be interested in a weaker result, for instance:

There exists $c<1$ such that for every convex pentagon, we have $\frac{\mathcal{Q}}{\mathcal{P}} \leq c$.

Comment: I have no idea if this could help, but notice that $Q$ is half of the sum of the five diagonals due to Thales' Theorem

Comment: The comment by DR. Mativa is interesting - the sum of the diagonals is twice the perimeter of FGHIJ. May be proving the diagonal sum maximum will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

COMMENT:

If we continue construction using mid points, we can see that all pentagons are  similar in regular and irregular pentagons. Let's denote the perimeters as $P_1$, $Q_1$, $P_2$, $Q_2$ . . etc. We have:

$\frac{2Q_1}{P_1}=\frac{2Q_2}{P_2}=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$

This is golden ratio in Fibonacci sequence. Considering the fact that an irregular polygon can be assumed as a transformed regular polygon ;this  is due to the fact that the sum of angle is always $(n-2)\pi$  , we may conclude that the ratio of perimeters obey similar rule.